# How to disable chrome autocomplete in searchbox of jQuery DataTable

Tags: html, google-chrome, datatables, autocomplete

Recently I have noticed that google chrome started to autocomplete all the search bars generated dynamically when we build jquery table. All these fields are not part of a form, but google decides to suggest login values in them. I have tried to resolve initialization callback and play with `autocomplete` property but none of the below solutions would do a trick. I haven't faced the same issue in Firefox/Safari. Any help in understanding the problem will be very much appreciated.

```
autocomplete="off"
autocomplete="false"
autocomplete="autocompleterandom"
```

here is how we initialize the table

```
newTable$.DataTable({
    paging: true,
    pageLength: 20,
    lengthMenu: [15, 30, 60, 80],
    search: {
        search: _this.searchValues[newTable$.data('type')]
    },
    initComplete: function() {
        $('.section input[type="search"]').prop('name', 'autocompleterandom');
        $('.section input[type="search"]').prop('autocomplete', 'autocompleterandom');
    }
});
```

here is how the generated search bar looks like

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_1_filter" class="dataTables_filter"> . 
    <label>Search:
        <input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_1" 
               name="autocompleterandom" autocomplete="autocompleterandom"> 
    </label>
</div>
```

after couple of hours researching this, it seems like a chrome "feature" and right now chrome suggests saved passwords all across the app :(

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue and the solution was putting these two lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='search']").wrap("<form>");
  $("input[type='search']").closest("form").attr("autocomplete","off");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This works fine:

```
initComplete: function() {
                $(this.api().table().container()).find('input').parent().wrap('<form>').parent().attr('autocomplete', 'off');
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all your solutions but no one works with me, this is how I have managed this issue:

```
preDrawCallback: function() {
                let el = $('div.dataTables_filter label');
                if(!el.parent('form').length) {
                    el.wrapAll('<form></form>').parent()
                    .attr('autocomplete', false)
                    .attr('autofill', false);
                }
            }
```

I use the preDrawCallback instead of the initComplete callback, but as the preDrawCallback is fired on each raw, I add an if statement to avoid multiple wrapping of form tag.

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
<input type="password" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">
```

Adding this code will be the easiest method

Read more -

[How do you disable browser autocomplete on web form field / input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags/23234498#23234498)

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/54805/filter-input-autocompleting-with-saved-username-in-chrome